# How do I trigger group membership was granted for a user - Group module

Tags: group

I try to use group module in d8.

**1. I created a new group type named `test`**
[image]

**2. I added 2 group as demo with admin is default `group_membership`.**

**3. in group 1 (name `okok`) I edited and added new user to group.**
[image]

**4. When I click the add member, the site redirect to another add form**:
[image]

- I enter the user as normal.
- then click save button.

**5. The result is User was added into that group.**

---

So, What I wonder is how to know an user:

- Was added to a group.
- Was removed from a group.

Because I want to call another service every time that action/event was executed. For example, I want to log in to the watchdog like:

- "User A has been added into group X"
- "User B has been remove from group Y"

Is there any way to trigger that action/event in code.

Thanks for all your helps.

Comment: Are those two separate examples, or are they connected?

Comment: I think they are separate, but my direction is dispatch event for `out-group` event also.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand what you are asking. Can you please try to add more information to the original question? Thank you.

Comment: @yaypan I updated the discription already, please check. Thanks - Thi

Comment: When you say 'event', is that in Drupal terms - do you want an Event Handler, or is it in generic terms, like 'when the user leaves a group, I want to perform this action'?

Comment: hi @Jaypan, I've just update the question. please let me know if you still hasn't been clear. Thanks

Comment: You can implement hook_group_content_insert() and hook_group_content_delete(), which are implementations of hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert() (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.8.x) and hook_ENTITY_TYPE_delete() (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_delete/8.8.x) respectively. These hooks are fired when a user is inserted into the database, and when the user is deleted from the database.

Comment: wait, is that adding user to groupe is creating a group content?

Comment: Yes. Group membership is created through entities of type `group_content`.

Comment: But note that nodes and other entities are also types of group content. So you'll need to check the type of entity being added inside those hooks.

Answer (score 0):

as @Jaypan suggested to me,
I used hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()
so my code is:

```
function hook_group_content_insert(GroupContentInterface $group_content) {
  if ($group_content->hasField('entity_id')
    && !$group_content->get('entity_id')->isEmpty()) {
    $users = $group_content->get('entity_id')->referencedEntities();
    $user = reset($users);
    if ($user instanceof UserInterface) {
      // Do your code here.
    }
  }
}
```